# Record Count for special criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get a count of Residents from the list below. If a resident is listed more than once and if the Enddate (record 1) is a day less than StartDate (record 2), then that resident should be counted just once.

So in the Example below, BEAL should be counted once,
CARVER should be counted twice,
CLAUS should be counted thrice.

Desired Output
**The Total Resident Count = 13.**

Not sure how to achieve this.

```
facility    Resident    StartDate   Enddate     Payer
ABC         AMMONS      9/12/2020   11/4/2020   Medicaid
ABC         ANDERSON    3/4/2020    11/18/2020  Medicaid
ABC         BEAL        1/1/2020    11/21/2020  Medicaid
ABC         BEAL        11/22/2020  11/24/2020  Medicaid
ABC         BEESON      10/26/2020  11/11/2020  Medicaid
ABC         BOLING      2/29/2020   11/20/2020  Medicaid
ABC         Boaring     5/13/2019   11/23/2020  Medicaid
ABC         BROCATO     11/12/2020  11/27/2020  Medicaid
ABC         BUSCH       3/9/2019    11/4/2020   Medicaid
ABC         CARVER      8/6/2020    11/1/2020   Medicaid
ABC         CARVER      11/6/2020   11/13/2020  Medicaid
ABC         CLAUS       5/7/2020    11/1/2020   Medicaid
ABC         CLAUS       11/5/2020   11/11/2020  Medicaid
ABC         CLAUS       11/12/2020  11/30/2020  Medicaid
ABC         CLAUS       12/15/2020  12/25/2020  Medicaid
```

Comment: ineffective date and effective date: is this end date and start date, respectively?

Comment: Yes... Sorry. I will revise Question

Comment: Here's what I'm interpreting: "If the end date of the first record is one day older than the start date of the next record of the same resident, count them twice." However, in your examples for Carver and Claus, those date ranges are more than a day. Did you mean to say "1+ day less"? For example, for Carver I see a 5 day difference and for Claus, 4 days.

Comment: Also, please provide a sample desired output

Comment: If the Enddate of the first record is 1 day less than the Startdate of the second record for the same resident, then that resident should be counted only once. So Carver and Claus should be counted twice, but Beal only once

Comment: @FabioFantoni _ the output I need is just 12 (which is the resident Count)

Comment: What if a resident appear in 3 different records? How about 4, 5,...?

Comment: @DVT -  Compare record 1 and record 2 , then compare record 2 and record 3 and so on.

Comment: Can you modify your question and add a few example for the case of 2 records, 3 records and different cases of the StartDate and EndDate and how to handle these cases? I think your question might be a lot more complicate than how you stated it.

Comment: @DVT - I have updated the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
; WITH cte AS (
SELECT Resident, StartDate, EndDate
, LAG( EndDate, 1, NULL ) OVER (PARTITION BY Resident ORDER BY StartDate) LastEndDate
FROM tmp
), cte1 AS (
SELECT Resident, StartDate, EndDate, LastEndDate
, ResidentCount = CASE WHEN StartDate <= DATEADD(day, 1, LastEndDate) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM cte
)
SELECT "Total Resident Count" = SUM(ResidentCount)
FROM cte1
```

Query to test

```
WITH tmp AS (
SELECT Resident, StartDate = CONVERT(Date, StartDate) , EndDate = CONVERT(DATE, EndDate)
FROM (
VALUES
 ('AMMONS','9/12/2020','11/4/2020')
, ('ANDERSON','3/4/2020','11/18/2020')
, ('BEAL','1/1/2020','11/21/2020')
, ('BEAL','11/22/2020','11/24/2020')
, ('BEESON','10/26/2020','11/11/2020')
, ('BOLING','2/29/2020','11/20/2020')
, ('Boaring','5/13/2019','11/23/2020')
, ('BROCATO','11/12/2020','11/27/2020')
, ('BUSCH','3/9/2019','11/4/2020')
, ('CARVER','8/6/2020','11/1/2020')
, ('CARVER','11/6/2020','11/13/2020')
, ('CLAUS','5/7/2020','11/1/2020')
, ('CLAUS','11/5/2020','11/11/2020')
, ('CLAUS','11/12/2020','11/30/2020')
, ('CLAUS','12/15/2020','12/25/2020')
) a (Resident, StartDate, EndDate)
), cte AS (
SELECT Resident, StartDate, EndDate
, LAG( EndDate, 1, NULL ) OVER (PARTITION BY Resident ORDER BY StartDate) LastEndDate
FROM tmp
), cte1 AS (
SELECT Resident, StartDate, EndDate, LastEndDate
, ResidentCount = CASE WHEN StartDate <= DATEADD(day, 1, LastEndDate) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM cte
)
SELECT "Total Resident Count" = SUM(ResidentCount)
FROM cte1
```

Comment: THANK  YOU. Works like a charm!

Comment: You can even eliminate cte1 by changing the last one to SELECT "Total Resident Count" = SUM ( CASE WHEN StartDate <= DATEADD(day, 1, LastEndDate ) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) FROM cte